# How to draw a rotated Image from its center in Slick2D?

Tags: java, image, slick2d, image-rotation

The problem is the following:
I have a position of lets say a spaceship and the position has to be defined in the middle of it (e.g. because of collision issues etc.). If the Spaceship would not be rotated, the image would be drawn like this:

`spaceship.draw(xPos - width/2 , yPos - height/2);`

The Spaceship is now Image in Slick2D, that has a random angle (0 <= angle <360), and still the position has to be defined at it's center. What slick does in the draw()-methods is the following:

[image]
It draws an oval around the image (i guess with the smallest possible surface area) and then looks where the line from the center at 135° off cuts the ellipse (red point) and sets that as position.

I still want to draw it centered, that means, i have to subract a value in both dimensions (`draw(xPos - xOff, yPos - yOff)`):

[image]

But im unabled to calculate that! Can someone help me please? I wasted two days to understand what the problem is...

Thanks a lot and Greets,
r

Here the rendering code:

```
> public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
> throws SlickException{
>           
>           // This sets all rotation to the middle of the graphics.
>           // The method works RELATIVE TO THE TOP-LEFT-CORNER OF THE IMAGE.
>           skin.setCenterOfRotation(skin.getWidth() * Revolve.getGS()/2 + Revolve.getXShift(),
>                   skin.getHeight() * Revolve.getGS()/2 + Revolve.getYShift());
>           
>           // This sets the Angle properly
>           skin.setRotation(angle);
>           
>           // This draws the image: xPos and yPos define THE CENTER of the Image.
>           skin.draw(
>               (float) (Revolve.getXShift() + Revolve.getGS() * xPos),
>               (float) (Revolve.getYShift() + Revolve.getGS() * yPos),
>               Revolve.getGS()
>           );
>     
>           // Draws the xPos and yPos of the Ship
>           g.setColor(Color.white);
>           g.drawOval(Revolve.getXShift() + Revolve.getGS() * xPos, Revolve.getYShift() + Revolve.getGS() * yPos, 2, 2);
>       }
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is your problem. You want to draw an image on a specific location and want to rotate it? If so I don't understand why you need such advanced concept. Please can you try to explain differently?

Comment: If you just want to rotate your image, why rotate doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Sorry for the 6 days off, I was on holiday, and it was great :-) Now to the problem: I can rotate the Image, thats easy. But after rotating it, I have to draw it (the rotated image) at a specific position (x,y). So, i say image.draw(x,y), but then x and y are not in the center of the image, but on the top left of the center. To be specific: at the drawn red point above. But i want to define the center of the rotated image, and there it has to be drawn. Is that clearer? Otherwise tell me please! Greets, r

Comment: Glad you had holidays! ;) can you post your code please?

Comment: Hallo Sir! I guess that won't help, as long as you don't understand, what exactly the problem is. I want to explain it again, and if you understand the problem, I will post the code. The problem: The Position of a rotated Image is not defined by its upper-left corner. Setting the center of rotation works perfectly. Rotating works perfectly. What does not work, is to draw a rotated image as expected, because i define its position at like 100,100 or whatever, and the upper-left corner is not at that position then!

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand. In my personnal code, I set the position to upper left and then rotate and it works. Please post your code. It will definitely helps.

Comment: I added some code above, here the context: This is the render method in the GameObject Class. All Game Objects extend this, so all Game Objects have a position (xPos, yPos) and a global Scale (Revolve.getGS()) and a Rotation. But I want the GameObjects to be drawn their center on the xPos and yPos, not their upper left corner. And around their own center, they have to be rotated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all becomes clear with some code.

Here is a solution:

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException
{
    this.character = new Image("/home/ronan/Images/20150517010612.jpg");
    this.scale = 0.5f;
    // When you set your center of rotation is is relative to your image ONLY.
    // this will make the center of my image to be the center of the rotation
    // NOTHING more to add
    this.character.setCenterOfRotation((this.character.getWidth()/2)*this.scale, (this.character.getHeight()/2)*this.scale);
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException
{
    this.rotation +=delta/10;
    this.character.setRotation(this.rotation);
}

public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException
{
    // Here I consider that my position is (500,500). then to draw it, I just substract hal the size of my image.
    // It will draw from top-lefft corner but based on my center.
    character.draw(500-(this.character.getWidth()/2)*this.scale, 500 - (this.character.getHeight()/2)*this.scale,this.scale);
}
```

I separate everything to be clear.

In the `init` method, you have to set you center of rotation. This center is relative to the image so just divide your width ad height by two to have the coordinate of the center of your image. when it work you multiply by you scale. Nothing more to add as it is really local for your image.

In the render method, to draw an image its always from top left corner. Just substract half width and half height to set use your center.

Just adapt this code to yours and it should go fine. Ask if you need more precision.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello RPresle (and other who seek help with similar problems). I made it, actually you made it. I used your code and it worked, but not perfectly from the beginning. There was a little shift, but I could fix it by involving the height in the line in the render() method (it uses width twice, that works only in square images). THANKS A LOT.

Comment: Glad you figure it out. I correct my code because it is clearly a mistake.